# Shell Script: Run Java jar files concurrently

Tags: java, python, shell

I have a Python script lets call it `foo.py` and I need to execute this first. After this script is finished executing I have to run about 10 Java JAR files (lets call it `waldo.jar`). I want to save time and have them run concurrently. How do I replicate this function in a shell script?

I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root
python3 foo.py 1> output.txt
java -jar waldo.jar fooArg barArg & # Jar 1
java -jar waldo.jar fooArg2 barArg2 & # Jar 2
java -jar waldo.jar fooArg3 barArg3 & # Jar 3
... and so on
echo "All Finished!"
```

I need those jar files running at the same time in the background.

Answer (score 0):

right before the end, you can add the following to wait for all child processes to finish.

```
echo "[$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] Waiting for subprocesses..";
for job in `jobs -p`
do
    echo $job
    wait $job
done
```